# Combination error? (PHP)

Tags: php

```
<?php 
if($_GET['token'] or $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token'] or $_SESSION['token2']) {
    echo 'not allowed';
} else {
    echo "";
?>

// other codes


<?  }; unset($_SESSION['token1'] or $_SESSION['token2']); ?> --> Line:112
```

I'm using the code above and I am getting the following combination error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR, expecting ',' or
>   ')' in ... line 112

Where the error am I doing?

Comment: please dont use key words `or`, `and` isnt it better to use `||`, `&&`?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish there? `if 'token2' is in either post/get and equal to the session value`?  That logic statement is just downright scary. I suggest you go look up basic PHP syntax before trying anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unset()` can only be used with variables. The expression `$_SESSION['token1'] or $_SESSION['token2']` is invalid parameter.

If you want to unset those two variables, use:

```
unset($_SESSION['token1'], $_SESSION['token2']);
```

You also don't need to use `;` after `}`.

Also, although your `if` statement is not syntactically invalid, it is giving the impression you want to test if `$_GET['token']` or `$_POST['token2']` are equal to `$_SESSION['token']` or `$_SESSION['token2']`, and if thats what you want to test here, you got it all wrong. You cannot test those things like that. You have to test all cases individually.

The logical approach would be:

```
if (
    $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token'] OR
    $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token2'] OR
    $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token2'] OR
    $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token2'] 
) {
```

Optionally, you have this resource too:

```
if (array_intersect(
    [$_GET['token'], $_POST['token2']],
    [$_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['token2']]
)) {
```

Although this is not the usual way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can only pass variables to `unset()`, not statements. *Always* read the manual to understand how to use functions properly.

```
unset($_SESSION['token1'], $_SESSION['token2'])
```

FYI, our IF statement is invalid. You can only make one comparison at a time in PHP:

```
if($_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token']
   or $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token'] 
   $_GET['token'] == $_SESSION['token2']
   or $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token2'] 
) {
```

You can also simplify this by using `$_REQUEST` which contains both POST and GET variables:

```
if($_REQUEST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']
   or $_REQUEST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token2'] 
) {
```

Comment: You've got a good point, but this isn't quite what's being asked. The error is happening in the unset, at the bottom of the code block.

Comment: Duh. Added that solution to my answer and made the rest an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

The `unset` keyword only works on variables, or array entries. In your code, the expression `$_SESSION['token1'] or $_SESSION['token2']` is resolved as a boolean (because of the `or` keyword), which cannot be unset. Therefore, the *syntax* for unset requires only a variable or an array entry, which explains that PHP chokes on the keyword `or`.

Also, your initial test is likely not what you meant, it will be evaluated as:

```
if(($_GET['token'] or $_POST['token2']) == ($_SESSION['token'] or $_SESSION['token2'])
```

(note the parentheses for precedence),
because `==` is non associative. Just like the unset expression, both sides of the equation will be evaluated as booleans, wihch means that if either array entry is *simply set* on each side, the `if` test will be taken as `true`.

Try this instead:

```
if($_GET['token'] ==  $_SESSION['token']  or $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token'] or  $_GET['token'] ==  $_SESSION['token2'] or $_POST['token2'] == $_SESSION['token2']){
// ...
<?php }; unset($_SESSION['token1'],$_SESSION['token2']); ?>
```